# Is shelve really slow and taking a lot of memory or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, shelve

I'm trying to write a program that uses a shelve database of sorted letters as key, and a list of words that can be created from them as values. e.g:

```
db['mnoo'] = ['moon', 'mono']
```

So I wrote a function that takes a filename and loads it into a shelve. The first part, that turns the file into a dictionary with the same layout as the shelve works fine, but the shelve part takes really long.

I'm trying it with a dictionary of ~100k entries, each value being a list. It seems to take 15-20 seconds for each 1000 enteries, and each entry seems to take ~1kb of space. Is this nromal?
the code:

```
def save_to_db(filename, shelve_in='anagram_db'):
    dct = anagrams_from_list(process_file(filename))

    with shelve.open(shelve_in, 'c') as db:
        for key, wordlist in dct.items():
            if not key in db:
                db[key] = wordlist
            else:
                db[key].extend(wordlist)
```

edit: just a quick clarification: each list in dict is about 1-3 words long, shouldn't be too large

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First -- yes, shelve's default pickle backend is slow and inefficient, and your best choice is to use something different.

Second -- you're making it worse by editing entries once they're there, rather than getting them into their final state in-memory before serializing them only once.

```
dct = anagrams_from_list(process_file(filename))
for key, wordlist in dct.items():
  content = {}
  for key, wordlist in dct.iteritems():
    if not key in content:
      content[key] = wordlist
    else:
      content[key].extend(wordlist)

for k, v in content.iteritems():
  db[k] = v
```

If you want an efficient database, I'd look elsewhere. tokyocabinet, kyotocabinet, SQLite, BDB; the options are numerous.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. So if I already have data in the database and I want to combine it with new data would it be faster to load everything, make changes, and then save it back? I'm actually using shelve just because I'm new to Python and reading "think python" and they use it there for some exercise. Probably won't use it again in the future :P.

Comment: Depends on how _much_ data you're changing; there's no one hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: shelve can use multiple backends like gdbm or bdb, only the fallback pickle backend is really slow.